# Difference in list of places shown by google map api and google+ app on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus

We would like to list "places" near user's current location.

We observed that list shown by Google+ app is richer and updated compared to list we get through web service of Google API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json).

Is there any way to find which webservice would provide results same as Google+?

(To find list of places in google+, 1. Open the Google+ app on android. 2. Click on Location 3. See the list).

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you not getting any results or are you just getting fewer results?  If you're just seeing 25 results, you would need to increase maxResults and then use the page token to get the full list.

Comment: @class we are getting results, but they do not match (have compared full result set) , G+ provides extensive list